# Dualboot Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.4 no sign of GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have installed Ubuntu several times now, but I am never able to boot in that partition. My UEFI/BIOS does not recognize it, and every boot option I have chosen leads to Windows booting. There is no sign that GRUB has even installed; Ubuntu is just sitting there unable to be used. I have an Asus M5A99FX Pro R2.0 mobo if that helps. Additionally Windows is installed to a 120gb SSD and Ubuntu to a ~60gb partition on a 1tb HDD (I could not install it to my SSD).

Answer (score 0):

Boot using your Ubuntu CD or USB drive.

Select the option to "Try Ubuntu".

Then install boot-repair ([See here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/boot-repair-fix-ubuntu-boot-issues.html))

Run boot-repair in advanced mode and be sure to click on "Advanced Options" and you may need to select secure boot or UEFI. (Sorry, I don't have the options in front of me right now, but went through this process last week).

Then click to run the repair and reboot.

Comment: One problem: my wireless adapter doesn't have a driver for Ubuntu so I cannot connect to the internet.

Edit: Getting the live image and burning that to a disk.